# Проблема с установкой расширения через Composer

Tags: json, yii2, composer

Добрый день всем) Возникла проблема при добавлении расширения yii2-firebird в yii2. Composer выдыёт такую вот ошибку:

[image: composer update]

Подскажите как исправить данную проблему?

**Файл composer.json** (Полностью стандартный файл в который была добавлена 1 строчка "edgardmessias/yii2-firebird": "*"

**Код composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced",
    "description": "Yii 2 Advanced Project Template",
    "keywords": ["yii2", "framework", "advanced", "project template"],
    "homepage": "http://www.yiiframework.com/",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "support": {
        "issues": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues?state=open",
        "forum": "http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/",
        "wiki": "http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/",
        "irc": "irc://irc.freenode.net/yii",
        "source": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2": "2.0.6",
        "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "*",
        "edgardmessias/yii2-firebird": "*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "~2.0.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "~2.0.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "~2.0.0",

        "codeception/base": "^2.2.3",
        "codeception/verify": "~0.3.1"
    },
    "config": {
        "process-timeout": 1800
    },
    "extra": {
        "asset-installer-paths": {
            "npm-asset-library": "vendor/npm",
            "bower-asset-library": "vendor/bower"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": "php init --env=Development --overwrite=n"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для работы с Yii2 нужен [Composer Asset Plugin](https://github.com/francoispluchino/composer-asset-plugin).

Выполните следующую команду:

```
php composer.phar global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:^1.2.0"
```

Comment: Команду выполнить в папке с composer.json? или вообще в любой директории? Пишет что не найден файл Composter.phar

Comment: Он ставит глобально, так что можно где угодно выполнить где есть доступ к composer.phar файлу или как там он у вас называется